# Prevent scrolling on only certain pages in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using iScroll on a single page in my Jquery Mobile document because it has some touch features and I wanted to prevent the user from accidentally scrolling away from the main content. So I add the event listener

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```

But I want this to only effect the main page where I have my iScroll enabled. So I figured I'd use the `pageload` event to bind the event listend to the specific page I needed.

```
$('#scroll').bind('pageload', function(){
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);// JavaScript Document
    });
```

But I still cant get it to work on the one page I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, got it

```
scroll.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); }, false);
```